# Gstreamer Camera Usage within Docker Containers

Tags: docker, gstreamer, x11, nvidia, egl

I'm currently working on running DL algorithms inside docker containers and I've been successful. However, I can only get it running by passing `--net=host` flag to `docker run` command which makes container use host computer's network interface. If I don't pass that flag it throws the following error:

```
No EGL Display 
nvbufsurftransform: Could not get EGL display connection
No protocol specified
nvbuf_utils: Could not get EGL display connection
```

When I do

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

it outputs `:0` which is correct.

But I don't understand what Gstreamer, X11 or EGL has to do with full network feature. Is there any explanation for this or any workaround except `--net=host` flag? Because of this reason I can't map different ports for various containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have created a topic on this on NVIDIA DevTalk Forum but it still is a dark spot for me. I didn't satisfied with the answers I got.

But it is OK to use `--net=host` flag to solve this problem anyways.

Answer (score -1):

**Quick heads up:** Gstreamer is not working over X11-Forwarding natively, you better have to use VNC solution, or have access to the physical machine.

**Troubleshooting**

- is gstreamer installed? `apt install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-base`
- what does `xrandr` returns?
- what does `xauth list` returns?
- what does `gst-launch-1.0 nvarguscamerasrc ! nvoverlaysink` returns?

**For example:**
On my setup because I do not use a dockerfile I copy the xauth list cookie then paste it in docker
`xauth add user/unix:11 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE cccccccccccccccccccccccccc`
After this I can test display with `xterm&`.
Besides, once this is done I have an output with `xrandr`

**Getting more verbose**
Also I connect to the docker by an ssh connection **with verbose** (to host / or / guest we don't care) `ssh -X -v user@192.168.123.123`
therefore the EGL error is wrapped by debug details.

**stream stuff**
This is related to Deepstream and Gstreamer customization from nVidia.
Some nvidia threads point that EGL needs a "sink" but no X11 display.
If there is some server running on the host at a designed port, running docker with --net=host will allow a client to connect within the docker.
According to the the doc, there are some servers used by the Gpu.

[Doc](https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/deepstream/4.0/dev-guide/index.html#page/DeepStream_Development_Guide%2Fdeepstream_app_config.3.2.html%23wwpID0ENHA)

**$DISPLAY**
According to [nVidia threads](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1063434/deepstream-sdk/-nano-nvbufsurftransform-could-not-get-egl-display-connection/post/5387641/#5387641): `unset DISPLAY` provides better results.
On my setup, without display, the EGL error is gone. Then the stream cannot be seen.

Comment: While these questions are probably a helpful guide to solve the problem, they will not be perceived as a full answer. (The downvote is not by me, but supports my point.) I recommend to avoid phrasing answers in the shape of rethoric questions. Instead I recommend to create what I call a conditional answer, e.g. "In case you problem is ... then the solution is ..." Also, instead of an extremely brief list of things to consider, it is usually perceived to be more helpful to phrase complete sentences. At least as an introduction and facit.